# C# Getting combobox.value to a path

Tags: c#, combobox, path, insert

Can anyone tell me why this code isn't working, please?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Z:\em\zud\"+comboBox1.SelectedValue+"\flag.xlsx");
        }
```

I want to use the selected item of a combobox and insert it in the middle of a path to open a file. I bet its a simple mistake, but I struggling to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what your comboBox1 datasource is. However, basically you forgot to add @ in front of your string literal to make it verbose:

"\flag.xlsx" should be:

@"\flag.xlsx"

Otherwise you are asking for \f (escaped).

Note: You might have used:

```
Path.Combine(@"Z:\em\zud", comboBox1.SelectedValue, "flags.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add @ after adding ComboBox value like this:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Z:\em\zud\"+comboBox1.SelectedValue+@"\flag.xlsx");
```

or you might have a look at:
`System.IO.Path.Combine`

Answer (score 0):

try to break down your process, then you can debug it line by line to see where it got wrong.

I think the root cause should be around filling the ComboBox, you may need to use SelectedItem. SelectedValue should be used when using binding.

Example:

```
    string selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem as string;
    string path = Path.Combine(@"Z:\em\zud\", selectedItem, "flag.xlsx");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```